# what is an alternative word or phrase for 'to check for'

Tags: word-choice

How would one express the concept of checking details in one document against another for verification or error?

Comment: In a formal context, I would ask them to proofread the new document against the original. In most cases I would ask them simply to proof the document.

Comment: See *compare*. Does that work for you?

Comment: Please provide more context, and a sample sentence.

Answer (score 1):

- To verify against _____
- To filter with respect to ______
- To correct and modify as found in _______

I assume that the process involves correction too.

Answer (score -1):

I would use 'to test for'.
According to Merriam-Webster Dictionary: 
TEST 
:to apply a test as a means of analysis or diagnosis 
—used with for:
To test for mechanical aptitude